# UIStackView zero height although I have content in it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have UIStackView in UITableViewCell and have four long text labels in it.
In first load I show only first label with 44 height in cell and hide other three and StackView shows properly.Then when I click on tableViewCell I need to expand cell and show other three labels. I show them and reload TableView but my StackView has zero height after that and all four label have zero height too. I hit this problem only with IOS 10.1 and when I use labels with short text StackView work well.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AboutUsTableViewCell
    cell.firstLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    cell.secondLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    cell.thirdLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    isExpanded = !isExpanded
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

[image: This is my xib]

[image: This is how looks like before click]

[image: This is after click]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You should update table after changing `isHidden` properties. That's should do a trick.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AboutUsTableViewCell
    cell.firstLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    cell.secondLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    cell.thirdLabel.hidden = isExpanded
    isExpanded = !isExpanded
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Also, check [this article](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/uistackview-table-cells) about using `UIStackView` inside `UITableView` cells

Answer (score 0):

Set the Labels number of lines to 0 and add below code to the viewDidLoad method.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 //or cell height
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: I already set UITableViewAutomaticDimension and all of my labels has 0 numer of lines. As I said everythink work perfect for IOS 9 and IOS 10.2 . I have problem only with IOS 10.1